# bootstrap form in react shows validation message before submit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-4

This is the code for `form validation in react`, but the `error message` is displaying for all field, `before im hitting submit button`, but i want to display error message only when im click on particular box, then corresponding error message should be displayed, if i did not even click on one of the box, then it should display either `green` or red, please help me to solve this issue.

```
render() {
    const { hospital_data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="register">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Sign Up</h1>
              <p className="lead text-center">Create your account</p>
              <form className="container was-validated" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} noValidate >
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="form-control-label" htmlFor="inputSuccess1">Your Name:</label>
                  <div className="col-xs-5 selectContainer">
                    <input id="inputSuccess1" type="text" className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Name" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onChange} required minLength="5" />
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">Enter atleast 5 characters.</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="col-xs-3 control-label">Language</label>
                  <div className="col-xs-5 selectContainer">
                    <select required name="hospital_id" className="form-control" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}>
                      <option value="">select hospital</option>
                      {hospital_data.map((item) =>
                      <option key={item._id} value={item._id}>{item.name}</option>
                    )}
                    </select>
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">Choose any 1 hospital.</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div ><label htmlFor="customRadioInline1">Choose Gender:</label></div>
                <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="gender" className="custom-control-input" value="male" onChange={this.onChange} required />
                  <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customRadioInline1">Male</label>
                </div>
                <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="gender" className="custom-control-input" value="female" onChange={this.onChange} required />
                  <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customRadioInline2">Female</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <div><label htmlFor="designation">Enter Designation:</label></div>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Designation" name="designation" value={this.state.designation} onChange={this.onChange} minLength="5" required />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">Enter your designation.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="email">Enter Your Mail ID:</label>
                  <input type="email" className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChange} required />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">Enter a valid Mail address</div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="password">Enter Password:</label>
                  <input type="password" className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onChange} minLength="5" required />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">Enter atleast 5 characters.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="confirm_password">Confirm Password:</label>
                  <input type="password" className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="confirm Password" name="confirm_password" value={this.state.password2} onChange={this.onChange} required />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">password should match.</div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
```

This is `picture` of how it looks, when i load the page.
[image]

Comment: @Colin https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-js9aw6

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit, check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nkpo2d?file=index.js).

Comment: @Colin what this line will do [`${e.target.name}Error`]:' '

Comment: It's a computed property. So, if `e.target.name` is e.g. "description", then it will be: `descriptionError`.

Comment: so,in the state, we have to add every field error object variable?

Comment: Sure, if you want. You can do it other ways but the way your code is would make it difficult. I'd recommend checking out the Semantic UI way of handling form errors. You don't really have to, since you can compute them all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169853/discussion-between-fun-world-and-colin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to store your errors on your state, and then only render them when they're not empty.

There's a short example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nkpo2d?file=index.js).